# How do I check if a file is an executable in nim?

Tags: linux, executable, nim-lang

How do I check if a file is an executable on Linux using Nim?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [getFilePermissions](https://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html#getFilePermissions%2Cstring) and check if a certain [FilePermission](https://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html#FilePermission) is in the set it returns.

```
import os

let isExecutable = fpOthersExec in getFilePermissions "./filename"
```

You'd probably want to check if all three different Exec variants are in it:

```
import os

proc isExecutable(filename: string): bool =
  let filePermissions = getFilePermissions filename
  fpUserExec in filePermissions and
    fpGroupExec in filePermissions and
      fpOthersExec in filePermissions
```